# How to fail Jenkins build (or mark it as unstable) if Symfony deprecation is found

Tags: symfony, jenkins, migration, phpunit, deprecation-warning

We are in process to migrate our code from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4.4 and would like to make sure no new deprecations are added to the code.

We are using phpunit-bridge and can see all deprecation warnings in the Jenkins build output.

But is there a way to fail a Jenkins build (or flag it as unstable) if any Symfony deprecation is found? To make sure that no new deprecations are being added to the code while the code is being migrated on a separate branch.

Comment: Provide more details about how you are running phpunit test. If you are using any bash script to run test, check for its exit code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `failOnWarning="true"` to your `phpunit.xml` to mark tests as failed when (depracation) warnings come up.

Example xml with the `failOnWarning` included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
        bootstrap="tests/autoload.php"
        colors="true"
        failOnWarning="true" <!--Here it is-->
>
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel"/>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="logFile=./var/log/deprecations.log"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="functional">
            <directory>./tests/Functional</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration">
            <directory>./tests/Integration</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener"/>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```